# AssertionError in unit testing

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

while I was writing tests I got that error

> ```
>  assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
> ```
>
> E       AssertionError: assert 415 == 201
>   E         -415
>   E         +201

**models.py**

```
class Product(TimeStamp):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
color = models.ManyToManyField(ColorOfProduct)
available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.category} - {self.name}'
```

**tests.py** looks like this

```
class ProductTest(APITestCase):
def post_product(self, category, name, brand_name, color, available):
    url = reverse(ProductView.name)
    print(url)
    data = {
        'category': category,
        'name': name,
        'brand_name': brand_name,
        'color': color,
        'available': available,
    }

    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    return response

def test_post_and_get_product(self):
    new_category_name = 'Hewlet Packard'
    new_product_name = 'HP Zenbook'
    new_brand_name = 'HP'
    new_color = 'black'
    new_available = True
    response = self.post_product(
        new_category_name,
        new_product_name,
        new_brand_name,
        new_color,
        new_available,
    )
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
    assert Product.objects.count() == 1
    assert Product.objects.get().name == new_product_name
```

I am indicating media type but when I check it throws error "Unsupported media type"

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please add your `ProductView` ? :)

Comment: @wencakisa thank you very much the problem was with my view)) I forgot that I included MultiParser in view that's why it was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might be django's default test format is `application/octet-stream`. You need to use `json.dumps()` before calling your test method. In your `post_product` method, just change:

```py
response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
```

to

```py
import json 

response = self.client.post(url, json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```